# Connecting to Oracle database(Not XE) without being on network

Tags: database, oracle11g

I installed Oracle 11g Standard Edition on my machine ( Windows 7 X64 ) and configured a listener. While being on the network , when I tried to connect through Jdev 11g , connection was successful. But when I'm off the network , I'm not able to connect to the Database thru Jdev. EM console is not opening too.

Is there any way I can connect to Database while I'm not on the network ?

Comment: What IP address did you configure your listener with? If it's your PC's externally-visible LAN IP then that won't exist when you're not on the network. Using localhost (127.0.0.1) would let you connect any time, but only from your PC - other machines wouldn't be able to connect to yours. You can always configure both if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listener has to be configured to listen to your `localhost` internal interface, `127.0.0.1`, for you to be able to connect when not on a network.

If it's only configured with your network adapter's IP address you will only be able to connect while on the network. When you unplug your LAN cable the interface associated with that IP is disabled and no longer reachable, even from within your PC. You will also have problems if your IP is allocated by DHCP, and would need to use a DNS name that follows reallocation; that's why servers usually have fixed IPs.

You can configure the listener to use both addresses if you need to be able to connect locally when off the network, but have other clients connect to your database when you are on the network. Having a DB that others need to access on a machine that isn't always connected would be a bit odd though.